# GCC verbose mode output explanation

Tags: linux, gcc, verbose

I'm new to linux. Can anyone explain to me the following verbose mode output for my hello world program? Also, what do the files `crt1.o`, `crti.o`, `crtend.o`, `crtbegin.o` and `crtn.o` and `lc` and `lgcc` do? Any other explanatory links are also welcome.

```
$ gcc -v hello.c

Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc-lib/i686/3.3.1/specs
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.3.1
 /usr/lib/gcc-lib/i686/3.3.1/cc1 -quiet -v -D__GNUC__=3 
 -D__GNUC_MINOR__=3 -D__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__=1 
 hello.c -quiet -dumpbase hello.c -auxbase hello -Wall
 -version -o /tmp/cceCee26.s
GNU C version 3.3.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
 compiled by GNU C version 3.3.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=51 
 --param ggc-min-heapsize=40036
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/i686/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include
 /usr/lib/gcc-lib/i686/3.3.1/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
 as -V -Qy -o /tmp/ccQynbTm.o /tmp/cceCee26.s
GNU assembler version 2.12.90.0.1 (i386-linux)
using BFD version 2.12.90.0.1 20020307 Debian/GNU
Linux
/usr/lib/gcc-lib/i686/3.3.1/collect2
 --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 -dynamic-linker
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /usr/lib/crt1.o /usr/lib/crti.o
 /usr/lib/gcc-lib/i686/3.3.1/crtbegin.o
 -L/usr/lib/gcc-lib/i686/3.3.1
 -L/usr/lib/gcc-lib/i686/3.3.1/../../.. /tmp/ccQynbTm.o
 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lc -lgcc -lgcc_eh
 /usr/lib/gcc-lib/i686/3.3.1/crtend.o
 /usr/lib/crtn.o
```

Comment: Here's one part of it: http://dev.gentoo.org/~vapier/crt.txt

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The first part is the version and configuration data for the compiler driver (that's the `gcc` binary, which is not actually the compiler itself):

```
Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc-lib/i686/3.3.1/specs
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.3.1
```

Then it prints the command it uses to call the real compiler, `cc1`:

```
 /usr/lib/gcc-lib/i686/3.3.1/cc1 -quiet -v -D__GNUC__=3 
 -D__GNUC_MINOR__=3 -D__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__=1 
 hello.c -quiet -dumpbase hello.c -auxbase hello -Wall
 -version -o /tmp/cceCee26.s
```

And `cc1` prints it's version and config info.

```
GNU C version 3.3.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
 compiled by GNU C version 3.3.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=51 
 --param ggc-min-heapsize=40036
```

Then `cc1` tells you what directories it will search for include files.

```
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/i686/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include
 /usr/lib/gcc-lib/i686/3.3.1/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

The compiler is now complete, so `gcc` tells you the assembler command it will use.

```
 as -V -Qy -o /tmp/ccQynbTm.o /tmp/cceCee26.s
```

And the assembler, `as`, gives its version info.

```
GNU assembler version 2.12.90.0.1 (i386-linux)
using BFD version 2.12.90.0.1 20020307 Debian/GNU
Linux
```

The assembler is now done so `gcc` gives the linker command. It's using `collect2` as an intermediary to the real linker `ld`, but that's not important here.

```
/usr/lib/gcc-lib/i686/3.3.1/collect2
 --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 -dynamic-linker
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /usr/lib/crt1.o /usr/lib/crti.o
 /usr/lib/gcc-lib/i686/3.3.1/crtbegin.o
 -L/usr/lib/gcc-lib/i686/3.3.1
 -L/usr/lib/gcc-lib/i686/3.3.1/../../.. /tmp/ccQynbTm.o
 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lc -lgcc -lgcc_eh
 /usr/lib/gcc-lib/i686/3.3.1/crtend.o
 /usr/lib/crtn.o
```

The linker gives no verbose output (try `-Wl,-v`), so that's it.

The "crt" files mean "C RunTime". They are small sections of code inserted at the start of your program, and at the end. They take care of initialising your global variables, heap, and stack. They call `atexit` functions after you return from `main`. And some more besides.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The linker does give verbose output if you set `-Wl,--verbose`.  It will print the attempts to acquire all inputs, including libraries.

Comment: This surely deserves more than +28!? Very helpful. Thank you @ams

Comment: In my gcc output I see `Configured with: --with-gmp-lib=/usr/local/lib --with-mpc-include=/usr/local/include`, does that mean header files and libraries must reside at those locations for gcc to work properly? Can those folder locations be overridden?

Comment: @raffian Those were the configuration settings for the `gmp` and `mpc` libraries that are needed to compile GCC itself. The configuration settings are recorded for posterity but are not typically of importance to the end user.

Comment: -Wl,-v did not give a full dump for me, but -Wl,--verbose did.  No space in the middle.  Link dumping is indeed separate from compiler --verbose dumping.